# Which Js Backend Framework for React Native woudl you recommend at the moment?

Tags: react-native, meteor, sails.js

Which Js Backend Framework for React Native would you recommend at the moment?

The main thing i will do you in the Backend is to Read and Write Data to the Database.
SQL Server and maybe Oracle

Meteor, Sails, Koa, Express or another one?
I've read alot about the Frameworks, but it seems everyone prefers another one.

What is your opinion

Answer (score 1):

Meteor is tightly integrated with MongoDB, though you can use [vlasky:mysql](https://github.com/vlasky/meteor-mysql). But you get the idea, it's best if you were to use it as is with MongoDB. So, this leave us with Sails, Koa, Express. They're kind of similar. BTW, Sails and Koa are built on top of Express. Now, the difference between the two is Sails follows batteries included philosophy so it comes with many built-in goodies, including Water ORM which you can connect to [different datasource](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/adapters/available-adapters).

All in all, it's better to not fall in the [paradox of choice](https://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/paradox-of-choice-in-web-development) and actually start building your application as soon as possible. ;)

Comment: Thank you, that paradox of choice is so true ^^. I will go with Sails and start the project today ;)

Comment: Best of luck, mate.